# How to compose two functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have three functions:

> $$f(x) = x+1 ,\; g(x) = x - 1 ,\; h(x) = 2x$$

I want to find $g\circ f$ such that $g(f(x))$, which equals $(x+1)-1=x$ but how?

I don't understand the steps.

Also, I want to find $h\circ f$ which equals $h(f(x)) = 2x-1$ but I dont know how to get that answer either.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! When you have a minute, please take the [tour of the site](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and look at [how to format mathematics here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) on Math SE. Also, I suggest that you bookmark this [very useful MathJax page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for quick reference. Cheers!

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this is function *composition*, not multiplication.

Comment: It should also be mentioned that $h(f(x))=2x+2$.  It is $g(h(x))$ which is equal to $2x-1$

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The function $f$ will take an input and return an output equal to one more than the input.

$f(\underbrace{\color{red}{x}}) = \underbrace{\color{red}{x}}+1$

Similarly $f(\underbrace{\color{red}{55}})=\underbrace{\color{red}{55}}+1$ and $f(\underbrace{\color{red}{8x^2-3}})=\underbrace{\color{red}{8x^2-3}}+1$

The function $g$ will take an input and return an output equal to one less than the input.

$g(\underbrace{\color{blue}{x}})=\underbrace{\color{blue}{x}}-1$

So, we have $(g\circ f)(x)=g(\underbrace{\color{blue}{f(x)}}) = g(\underbrace{\color{blue}{x+1}})=(\underbrace{\color{blue}{x+1}})-1 = x+1-1=x$

Similar manipulation can be done for $h$

Comment: I'm colour blind

Comment: @mrnovice added underbraces as well to add the emphasis that the color was intended to provide.  The end result is to recognize that functions are machines that transform an *input* into an *output* in a designated way in terms of the input, regardless what the input looks like be it simply $x$ or something more complicated (*e.g. another function*).

Comment: Was actually joking(if it was true how would I know there was colour lol), but perhaps some innocent colour blind soul will be helped by the change some years from now, +1

Comment: Red-blue colour blindness is very rare, by the way. (A red-blue colour-blind person could usually still see that the colour was different to black; just couldn't necessarily distinguish between the two. Perhaps someone completely achromatic might not be able to distinguish them, but that condition is even rarer.) Red/green is the most common.

Comment: Colorblindness aside, this is a very nice way of illustrating what is going on.

Comment: While color-blindness that could not make this distinction is rare, uncooperative browsers are more common. The I.E. version I have at work (11, I think - IT keeps us well behind the times) does not display colored mathjax, despite showing other colored text. So the added underbraces are welcome.

Comment: People should keep in mind that there's an actual distinction between a person who's more properly called color-*deficient* (like me, on red/green; aka "daltonism") and one that is really color-*blind*.

Answer (score 2):

$g(f(x))$ means you substitute $f(x)$ in wherever you see $x$ in $g(x)$, therefore we get $g(f(x)) = (x+1)-x = x$

Performing the same for $h(f(x))$, we get $h(f(x)) = 2(x+1) = 2x + 2$

Comment: Yes, and f(h(x)) = 2x +1 so that means h o f is not equal to f o h. Cheers, I know now.